# reactjs issue with anchor while using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I have a problem where I really do not know what to do.

I have an element where I want to get the anchor and write it to a local state. The only problem is that this leads to an invalid anchor.

```js
<StyledHeader
   avatar={
      <Avatar
         className="md:mx-4"
         alt="user photo"
         src={user.data.photoURL}
      />
   }
   title={row.commentUser}
   onMouseEnter={(ev) => {
      ev.preventDefault();
      handlePopup(ev, row.id);
   }}
/>
```

I had a Console.log output without setAnchorEl and that successfully pointed to the DOM element.

```js
  function handlePopup(event, id) {
    const target = { ev: event.currentTarget };
    console.log(target);
  }
```

Browser: Linked to DOM, and worked as expected.

However, as soon as I use setAnchorEl, my console tells me that it doesn't exist in the DOM.

```js
  function handlePopup(event, id) {
    const target = { ev: event.currentTarget };
    console.log(target);
    setForm({ anchor: event.currentTarget, id: id });
  }
```

> Output Browser: Node cannot be found in the current page.

Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem:
The reason was that I created the definition of the StyledTableCell and StyledTableHeader inside the component.
Once these are created outside the component, everything works as usual